# MVVM CoreData FetchedReusltsController

Tags: objective-c, mvvm, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am trying to start using `MVVM` with `Objective-c` but I get some problems with `CoreData`. I don't know who should handle the `fetchedResultsControllerDelegate` methods. The `viewModel` or the `viewController`?

I think that the viewModel should handle it, but I see too much code to do the same.

Comment: what are your reasons? and do you see view models as lightweight transient things or longer term persistent things - i.e. destroyed when the cell is reused or maintained in a big array?

Answer (score 4):

Let's say you have an edit button in a view. Edit button is hidden when there are no objects in fetchResultsController and you want to show it when any objects are added.

If you implement `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` in viewController:

- ViewController gets notifications about changes of model
- ViewController must notify ViewModel that something happened with the
  model
- ViewModel has to change value of the editButtonShown
  property
- ViewModel must notify the viewController to update the
  view

If you implement `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` in viewModel:

- model notifies the viewModel about the change
- viewModel changes the editButtonShown
  property and sends notification to viewController

If you implement these methods in viewController then it gets reference to the model and this should not happened in MVVM

`- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath`

I think that correct solution is to implement the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate`in ViewModel. Then you should have similar protocol to notify the viewController to update the view, but it should work with viewModels, not with the models

Comment: I have been debating this myself and am still not convinced by your answer however it does give some clarity. I am especially confused as to what to do with my `tableView`? Wouldn't there be a lot of unnecessary back-n-forth to update the `tableView` when my `NSFetchedResultsController` gets a `didChangeObject`?